# Check if user is active before allowing user to sign in with devise (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using devise and created a User field called :active which is either true or false.  I have to manually make the user active (true) before the user is allowed to log in. At least that is the intent.  I have tried this...

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    "resource/signin CREATE"
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    unless resource.active?
      sign_out
      redirect_to :sorry_not_active_url
      return
    end
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end  
end
```

However this does not catch all the places where a user can log in, for example, when a user changes their password, the site automatically logs them in automatically after. However, if the user is not active, I do not want them to be allowed to log in, but rather be redirected to a sorry_not_active_url.

What would be the best way to prevent the user from signing in if the user is not active?

Thank you.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Add these two methods to your user model, devise should pick them up automatically - you should NOT need to extend `Devise::SessionsController`

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && self.your_method_for_checking_active # i.e. super && self.is_active
end

def inactive_message
  "Sorry, this account has been deactivated."
end
```

Comment: This great! is there a way to check for different states, like, active, not active, pending, rejected by creating a field with 4 different values and deliver a different message for each state?

Comment: after thinking about it, I assume I could make def inactive_message reference a field, and the field could have a custom message per user.  Does this seem correct?

Comment: For Devise 4.7 these methods instead need to be added to the model you use for authentication, usually User, i.e. not to the SessionsController

Comment: without explanation this is feels like a hack and magic because there is no doc that mention about this. but devise has the code in [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/8593801130f2df94a50863b5db535c272b00efe1/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb) and [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/8593801130f2df94a50863b5db535c272b00efe1/lib/devise/hooks/activatable.rb)

Answer (score 7):

Devise (If you have devise 3.2+) now support [`block`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.2/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L18) parameter in (session) create

```
# assuming this is your session controller

class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

def create
  super do |resource|
     unless resource.active?
      sign_out
      # you can set flash message as well.
      redirect_to :sorry_not_active_url
      return
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Viren, would you be able to list a couple of benefits to doing it this way as opposed to the implementation in the accepted answer? I'm looking to implement this now myself and am wondering what's the current best practice. Thanks.

Comment: @Marklar This might be beneficial when you support multiple authentication strategies and need to disable the regular authentication flow, but not for all. While the OP's use case is for checking if a user is active, I have needed to disable regular session creation if a user has authenticated via another method (OAuth) for example. The model based approach using `active_for_authentication?` would have been more difficult.