# Devise signs in an user even though it (in theory) never reached the sign_in method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have an attribute (approved) on the user that i wish for devise to consider before allowing sign in.

I've overriden the session controller and its currently as follows:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_after_filter :verify_authorized

  def create

    user = User.find_by_email(params[:user].try(:[], :email))

    unless user.approved?
      flash[:alert] = "Login fail. Account currently pending approval."
      redirect_to :back and return
    end

    resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  def failure
    head 403
  end
end
```

Looking at the logic i see that there is a "redirect_to :back" happening, but then it seems devise takes over, logs in the user regardless of that and redirects to root (which is what i've setup to redirect to upon login)

I've never worked with devise before and this is driving me mad. I should return before reaching the 'sign_in' part but something is happening that it still signs in the user regardless of my unless block.

How could i go about intercepting that login if user.approved == false ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Although not the same question, the top answer in this question applies here and fixed the issue for me.

[Check if user is active before allowing user to sign in with devise (rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864554/check-if-user-is-active-before-allowing-user-to-sign-in-with-devise-rails)