# Ruby on Rails: Edit Sessions controller create action to check if user is active

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I need to alter the Sessions controller create method to first check if the user has a column filled out for `deactivation_date`.

If that column has a value, the user IS deactivated and the sign in authentication should fail in the same way as if the user doesn't exist.

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController



    def create
        logger.debug('create')
        self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
        if self.resource.deactivation_date?
            logger.debug('user has been deactivated')
            flash.now[:notice] = "Sorry, this account has been deactivated."
        else

            set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
            sign_in(resource_name, resource)
            respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        end
      end


end
```

I've tried overriding the sessions controller as well as the create method.

My code above is only preventing a redirect. Once I refresh the page, the user is authenticated no matter what.

Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can do this by overriding the default `sessions_controller` from Devise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way to do this is really just add a custom valid_for_authentication? method in the resource devise is using, so in Users.rb:

```rb
def valid_for_authentication?
    super && !deactivation_date?
end
```

Comment: I only want to edit a piece of the functionality. I'm not sure how I can do that. I'm taking over a project someone else made. The custom registration controller has many methods. Can you show me an example?

Comment: I checked some examples but the most simple way to do this is really just add a custom valid_for_authentication? method in the resource devise is using, so in Users.rb:

```ruby
def valid_for_authentication?
    super && !deactivation_date?
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I just found that exact solution haha

Comment: No worries haha I am going to edit the answer for other people that might come here looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this question: [Check if user is active before allowing user to sign in with devise (rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864554/check-if-user-is-active-before-allowing-user-to-sign-in-with-devise-rails)

I was able to simply add a method to my User model and devise picked it up automatically

In my user model:

```
  def active_for_authentication?
    super && !self.deactivation_date
  end
```

I didn't know at first the method name was specific to devise. has to be exactly `active_for_authentication?`